# how can get value separately of a query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

in MVC3 asp.net this is my controller statement:-

```
ViewBag.rawMaterialRequired = (from x in db.RawMaterial
join y in db.ProductFormulation on x.ID equals y.RawMaterialID
where y.ProductID == p select new { x.Description, y.Quantity });
```

this is my View Code related to it:-

```
@foreach(var album in ViewBag.rawMaterialRequired)
{
            @album<br />
}
```

So output is:-

```
{ Description = Polymer 26500, Quantity = 10 }
{ Description = Polymer LD-M50, Quantity = 10 } 
{ Description = Titanium R-104, Quantity = 20 }
```

but i need this type of answer:-

[image]

please suggest me what should i do for it?
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a RawMaterial  class

```
public class RawMaterial
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

and use it instead of anonymous object

```
ViewBag.rawMaterialRequired = (from x in db.RawMaterial
join y in db.ProductFormulation on x.ID equals y.RawMaterialID
where y.ProductID == p select new RawMaterial { x.Description, y.Quantity });
```

and the view

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>

@foreach(var album in ViewBag.rawMaterialRequired)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@album.Description</td>
        <td>@album.Quantity</td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you sir... Your answer is appropriate.  Sir i get a error when i run my program that "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Description' and 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Quantity'", what should i do for this ? should i take some thing else other than ViewBag ?

Comment: Yes Sir, as you suggest i have created public class RawMaterial
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}   now how can get result of this query into object of this class.?

Comment: Dear sir i appreciate your help. Sir this error is occured "
Cannot initialize type 'CalcoWOMS.Models.RequiredRawMaterial' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'" in your controller line please suggest me please...